# cross ratio - how to calculate values with it?

Tags: projective-geometry

I have this scenario [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJzUs.png). It is a projective image.
[image: here]

1. What would be the cross-ratio formula for these points?: $$v,c_{r},r_{2},r_{1}$$

2.And let be $$dst(r_{2},r_{1})=30cm$$ in the real world. How can I calculate the other values (distances) between the points given in 1.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out myself:
Look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKdJB.png) picture.

[image: parallel and perspective projections]

a is the real world and b is the projective image of it. The interesting thing is that the cross ratio of the points v,cr,r2,r1 in picture a is the same as the cross ratio in picture b. That´s called invariance. So the following relationship can be written in a formula:
[THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6IUA.png) explaines the rest.

[image: formulas for cross ratio computation]